# Importing SolidColor for use in an adobe upx plugin

Tags: javascript, adobe, photoshop-script

I'm trying to create a SolidColor object following the basic example given in the API documentation:

https://developer.adobe.com/photoshop/uxp/2022/ps_reference/classes/solidcolor/

However it is not recognized as a type and I can't find an example of it being imported. Has anyone encountered this?

I tried to find an example of a proper import (or rather require()) for the class but I can't find one and don't know if it's just supposed to be global.

Here is the error I'm encountering:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: SolidColor is not defined

Answer (score 0):

The `SolidColor` class is bound to the `Photoshop` class same as other classes.
It is not documented yet, but it has been there since the end of 2021. It should appear in the [documentation](https://developer.adobe.com/photoshop/uxp/2022/ps_reference/classes/photoshop/#properties) in a few weeks.

You can do:

```
const SolidColor = require("photoshop").SolidColor;
const color = new SolidColor();
```